# Switching between activities with no flash

Tags: android, xml, flash

I've searched long and hard for an answer to this question but can't find any answers. 
My problem is that I created an XML file with 5 buttons on it and each button is linked to another xml file. Once clicked, the button takes you to the next xml file with the same 5 buttons in the same location. The problem I face is that when the pages are switching, there is an ever so slight flash of black. Then there's a second where the toolbar loads. How do I fix this annoying lag and make it fluid?

Comment: Why do not just change button properties (color, text if necessary , onclick listeners) in current activity? Do you  overridePendingTransition to no animation?

Comment: @aelimill yeah so I have a theme with a line of code that removes any animation. Before, the page would jump up. Now, it stays flat and that's good but it take an obvious second to load the buttons AND the toolbar. Any fix? Is there a way to include everything in one content_main.XML? I have a different XML file for each button

Comment: You can reuse XML component with <include layout="" /> in other xml. I do not know the logic of your application, but you can remove, for example, container with your buttons and add another. Or rewrite on fragments

Comment: @aelimill yes. So I have the main activity and a content main that I include in the main activity. Then I have a Java file called ActivityMain. The Java file has each button linked to another Java file when clicked. Each other Java file is almost an identical clone to the main one, and each one calls almost identical XML files that have different buttons pressed and different page content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of switching between activities you can simply change between the layout xml files.

xml layout1

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="New Button"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:onClick="newLayout"/>
```

java code

```
 public void newLayout(View view) {
    setContentView(R.layout.new_layout);

}
```